# Uber SDK installed but can't be import in project using COCOAPOD

Tags: swift, xcode, uber-api

I want to use uber SDK in my project .i am using Xcode 8.3.3
 I have installed it with cocoa pod method. it includes user scripts in the project but doesn't import its library in the project. I have also tried cartage method but it shows

"*** Fetching rides-ios-sdk**
 Fetching ObjectMapper
 **Downloading rides-ios-sdk.framework binary at "v0.6.0"**
 Checking out rides-ios-sdk at "v0.6.0"
 **Checking out ObjectMapper at "1.5.0"
*** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/hc/bcjcqz9x2hb84g5_2786z85w0000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.vE5KMz.log
*** Building scheme "ObjectMapper-iOS" in ObjectMapper.xcworkspace
Build Failed
    Task failed with exit code 65:
    /usr/bin/xcrun xcodebuild -workspace /Moghees/Driver_APP/Carthage/Checkouts/ObjectMapper/ObjectMapper.xcworkspace -scheme ObjectMapper-iOS -configuration Release -derivedDataPath /Users/mac/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/ObjectMapper/1.5.0 -sdk iphoneos ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CARTHAGE=YES clean build (launched in /Moghees/Driver_APP/Carthage/Checkouts/ObjectMapper)

This usually indicates that project itself failed to compile. Please check the Xcode build log for more details: /var/folders/hc/bcjcqz9x2hb84g5_2786z85w0000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.vE5KMz.log"

Help me out.

Comment: can you show your podfile?

Comment: my pod file contains this code use_frameworks!

target 'Driver_App' do
pod 'UberRides'
end

Comment: using this link https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/button/ios